# Nuxt JS installing umd Vue plugin/component throws unknown custom element

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've written a Vue JS component/plugin and have it in the following formats:

- Common
- ESM
- UMD

I'm trying to import the UMD version into my Nuxt JS project (I'e also tried the others) and use it.

I've added a `scripts` array to my **nuxt.config.js** file to the `head` section:

```js
scripts: [
  { src: '/js/vue-les-offers.umd.js' }
]
```

My JS file lives in **static/js**, and I've gone ahead and included my component in my page:

```html
...
<vue-les-offers></vue-les-offers>
...
```

But I'm getting an error thrown in my console:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

What am I missing?

I've tried:

- installing via the plugins array
- installing via the modules (used the ESM variant)
- tried wrapping in a client-only element
- tried both min and non-minified JS variants

Comment: This error is saying that your component is not registered: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration-in-a-Module-System

Comment: Okay, but I'm already aware of this. As state above, my component is installed via my JS plugin file and should be available at runtime. Why isn't it despite loading my UMD file?